# IntelliJ Maven WAR with Chrome Developer Workspaces

Tags: java, javascript, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to use IntelliJ to do my web development.

With Eclipse I didn't use a Maven build and simply changed between Chrome Dev Tools and Eclipse when I would need to switch between frontend and backend changes and was able to map the Chrome workspace to a static webapp folder that wasn't part of a Maven build.

Now I've switched to IntelliJ (mainly for its Java tools) but now I'm unable to use it alongside Chrome Dev Tools.

I have the 'Update Resources' on frame deactivation set, which works if I edit a local javascript file and then move away or save the file, but if I try to use Chrome Dev Tools Workspaces to save it, obviously IntelliJ doesn't pick up that the file has been externally updated and therefore doesn't update the file in the exploded WAR.

Is there some way I can do these together? I like a lot of things about IntelliJ for Java development, but I find that Chrome is far and away the best IDE for Javascript/CSS/HTML changes and would like to use it alongside IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it is much easier to simply compile the web app in place into WEB-INF rather than using maven. You can still use maven for dependencies but just ignore the maven lifecycle for local development. It's not necessary for local development and adds time to the compilation/deploy process.

Let me know if this is a bad idea. It has worked quite well for me.